# offline installation of video plugins

Tags: 11.10, vlc, plugins, codecs, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Please help
I installed Ubuntu11.10 32bit in an IBMTP41 notebook, that is NOT connected to the internet,
tried running video files such as .mp4,.flv,.avi,.Xvid, in Movie Player but it asks for plugins, see the list below

```
mp4: MPEG-4 AAC decoder; H.264 decoder
flv: SorensonSpark Video decoder; MPEG-1 Layer3(MP3) decoder
avi: MPEG-1 Layer3 (MP3) decoder; MPEG video decoder
XviD: AC-3 (ATSC A/52) decoder; XviD MPEG-4 decoder
```

how do i donwload (from another computer with internet) and install all these plugins and their dependencies.

I also want to install the VLC Media player and its dependencies

I assume this is related to the restricted codecs and I have tried donwnload/install them with no success.

I'll appreciate all ur help

Answer (score 0):

If you search the following in to google:

MPEG-4 AAC decoder download
H.264 decoder flv download 
VLC media player download

and all the other ones with download on the end.Then insert a USB/CD (They will both work) Then when it prompts you to download the file click 'Save'. Then it will ask you where. Save it in your CD/USB. Then go to your computer and insert your drive. Launch the files and you are up and away!

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but when trying 2 install it lacks dependencies and I have found no way to download everything it asks for.  If u can recommend a way to download _Every_ package needed for say MPEG-4 AAC and H.264 decoder I'll appreciate it